# RxJava2: need help to fix an issue in code

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am newbie in RxJava programming and need help to handle an issue with my code. I have the following code:

```
public Single<List<Modifications>> loadModificationsImages() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(DataStoreRepository::loadModifications)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
            .doOnNext(item -> {
                Observable.fromIterable(item.images)
                        .forEach(image -> {
                            ApiRepository.getModificationsImages(item.id, image.id)
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                                    .retry(3)
                                    .subscribe(response -> {
                                        InputStream is = response.byteStream();

                                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

                                        String contentSubType = response.contentType().subtype();
                                        String fileName = "modifications_id_" + item.id + "_image_id_" + image.id + "." + contentSubType;
                                        FileUtil.saveBitmap(bitmap, fileName);

                                        Modifications.Images img = new Modifications.Images(image.id, fileName, image.type);
                                        DataStoreRepository.updateModificationsImage(img, item.id);
                                    });
                        });
            })
            .toList();
}
```

It works perfectly, but I need to collect each `Modifications.Images` into a collection and pass it to a method (`DataStoreRepository.updateListOfModificationsImage(List<Modifications.Images> images, int id)`) for updating a database. So, the issue with this line:

```
Modifications.Images img = new Modifications.Images(image.id, fileName, image.type);
DataStoreRepository.updateModificationsImage(img, item.id);
```

It just overrides a record in a database with single item. I've tried to modify the given code with applying Collection but it did not work for me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: first of all avoid making Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing inside a callback is almost always wrong. Otherwise, you should `toList` the images and then call the batch update method:

```java
public Single<List<Modifications>> loadModificationsImages() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(DataStoreRepository::loadModifications)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
            .flatMapSingle(item -> 
                Observable.fromIterable(item.images)
                .flatMap(image ->
                    ApiRepository.getModificationsImages(item.id, image.id)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .retry(3)
                    .map(response -> {
                        InputStream is = response.byteStream();

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

                        String contentSubType = response.contentType().subtype();
                        String fileName = "modifications_id_" + item.id + "_image_id_"
                            + image.id + "." + contentSubType;
                        FileUtil.saveBitmap(bitmap, fileName);

                        Modifications.Images img = new Modifications.Images(
                            image.id, fileName, image.type);
                        return img;
                    })
                )
                .toList()
                .doOnSuccess(images -> 
                    DataStoreRepository.updateListOfModificationsImage(images, image.id)
                )
            );
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful. Thank you!